# Redirect desktop folder to another folder in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, shortcuts, dropbox, folder-redirection

Most of us save many of our files directly to Desktop (i.e. `users\[myUser]\Desktop`). I use cloud storage like Dropbox and Google Drive and others. So for revision history, every time I need to manually copy my files on Desktop to my Dropbox folder.

Is there any tips or tricks to add the Desktop folder to my dropbox or redirect it? For other folders, you can create a shortcut to its original folder stored on Dropbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Desktop` folder is actually in `C:\Users\[user name]\Desktop`, and you can make links to it.

[image: Desktop folder location]

That said, it might not be a good idea to specify all the `Desktop` for backup because there are other hidden folders and links in that location. For example, it's possible `This PC` could get copied over, meaning **everything** on your machine.

[image: Other folders and links in Desktop]

Perhaps create a folder or two in `Desktop` for files you want backed up, rather than `C:\Users\[user name]\Desktop`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm currently doing now. I don't want to go in that folder every time !